# Could not open file perl

Tags: perl, xslt, libxslt

I am trying to convert a plist files into a JUnit style XMLs. I have a xsl stylesheet which converts the plist to JUnit/ANT XML.

Here is the perl code which I run to convert the plist to XML:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet_file("\\\~/Hudson/build/workspace/ui-automation/automation\\\ test\\\ suite/plist2junit.xsl");

my $counter = 1;
my @plistFiles = glob('Logs/*/*.plist');
foreach (@plistFiles){
    #Escape the file path and specify abosulte path
    my $plistFile = $_;
    $plistFile =~ s/([ ()])/\\$1/g;
    $path2plist = "\\\~/Hudson/build/workspace/ui-automation/automation\\\ test\\\ suite/$plistFile";
    #transform the plist file to xml
    my $source = $parser->parse_file($path2plist);
    my $results = $stylesheet->transform($source);

    my $resultsFile = "\\\~/Hudson/build/workspace/ui-automation/automation\\\ test\\\ suite/JUnit/results$counter.xml";
    #create the output file
    unless(open FILE, '>'.$resultsFile) {
    # Die with error message
    die "\nUnable to create $file\n";
    }

    # Write results to the file.
    $stylesheet->output_file($results, FILE);
    close FILE;
    $counter++;
}
```

After running the perl script on Hudson/Jenkins, it outputs this error message:

> Couldn't open ~/Hudson/build/workspace/ui-automation/automation\ test\ suite/Logs/Run\ 1/Automation\ Results.plist: No such
>   file or directory

The error is caused by `my $source = $parser->parse_file($path2plist);` in the code. I am unable to figure out why it cannot find/read the file.

Anyone know what might be causing the error?

Comment: Really? With a filename like `~/Hudson/build/workspace/ui-automation/automation\ test\ suite/Logs/Run\ 1/Automation\ Results.plist:` you can't figure out why it can't find the file?

Comment: @friedo What? it cant take a file path???

Comment: @friedo I am not sure what you mean by your comment, can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three obvious error in the path mentioned in the error message.

```
~/Hudson/build/workspace/ui-automation/automation\ test\ suite/Logs/Run\ 1/Automation\ Results.plist
```

Those are:

1. There's no directory named `~` in the current directory. Perhaps you meant to use the value of `$ENV{HOME}` there?
2. There's no directory named `automation\ test\ suite` anywhere on your disk, but there is probably one named `automation test suite`.
3. Similarly, there's no directory named `Run\ 1` anywhere on your disk, but there is probably one named `Run 1`.

Comment: Escaping is used when inserting one thing in another. You had two levels of escaping, but only one level of embedding (string in Perl source code).